# When does MemoryCache get cleared in .Net web app?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, caching, memorycache

I am using MemoryCache in a MVC, and Web API application, to cache objects. I am initializing the cache in my Global.asax.cs.

IE:

```
MemoryCache c = new MemoryCache(cacheNamespace);
var cacheItem = new CacheItem(key, value);
c.Add(cacheItem, cachePolicy);
```

However, I am wondering when does this cache get freed up? When I restart my app? This is assuming I don't run out of memory of course.

Comment: Short answer: when it needs to.

Comment: @HenkHolterman What's the long answer? :)

Comment: How are you initizling your cache?

Comment: @PrestonGuillot Updated my question. I'm just instantiating MemoryCache, and adding new items to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your question is when `cacheItem` gets freed up - it will depend on the `cachePolicy`.

However, if your question is when `MemoryCache` object gets freed up. Answer is `Never` because it is held up by internal timer callbacks. You have to Dispose the object to free it up.

`MemoryCache` is pretty heavy object and you should create your own instance only when you really require it. In general case use `MemoryCache.Default` instance.